# At which point in time is the series colour initialised in a chart graph

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, mschart

I use `Chart` to draw a graph with 2 lines. Now my aim is to set the `LineColor` of the `MajorGrid` of the second Y-axis to the color of the corresponding line. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<double> values_1 = new List<double>();
    List<double> values_2 = new List<double>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        make_values();

        for (int i = 0; i < values_1.Count; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(values_1[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values_2.Count; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[1].Points.AddY(values_2[i]);
        }

        // set the colour of grid to corresponding line
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineColor = chart1.Series[1].Color;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void make_values()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
        {
            values_1.Add(Math.Sin(i / 60.0));
            values_2.Add(Math.Cos(i / 60.0));
        }

    }
}
```

Since the colours are chosen automatically for the 2 different series I though I could just grab the colour. But when debugging I see that the colour is (0,0,0):

[image]

So the grid colour does not change. But the colour of the second series is not (0,0,0) as can be seen when the window is loaded!:

[image]

If I force and set manually the colours of the 2 series before that. Everything  works fine, and the grid gets the corresponding colour.

Does anyone know at which point in time I would have to grab the colour of the series to get the real value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the Series Colors you need to call `ApplyPaletteColors`. This is necessary when you want to use them for other elements or when custom drawing. You should also call it again after changing the  [palette](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartcolorpalette%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

```
chart1.ApplyPaletteColors();
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.applypalettecolors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Remarks
>
> When the Chart colors are automatically assigned at run time, there is
>   no way to know what the colors will be prior to the time when the
>   chart rendered; the Color property of an automatically assigned value
>   will return Empty at this time.
>
> If you call the ApplyPaletteColors method, the colors for the series
>   and the data points will be set, which allows for programmatic access.

Comment: brilliant! thank you very much. I definitely should read more often the Remarks section ;)

Comment: ah I did not follow the link immediately, I thought it would be in the remarks of the `Chart` class documentation. Well yes exactly, finding the right method out of roughly 100. But through your answer I will in future think about automatic assignment of properties differently. Next time I will consider the possibility that there is a method that forces the values to be initialised.